# Kivy, is there a way to change all button properties within a layout only

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Is there a way to change the button properties with <Button> but only in a spectified Layout ?

I don't want to change the size during the execution, i just don't want to write it for all buttons but just once in MyLayout.

Example: In my code below i want something which change the Size of all my buttons in MyLayout but not in LoadFilePicker.

Colin

```
MyLayout:
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "top":0.95}
        text:"Import config"
        on_release:
            root.loadPicker()

    Button:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":0.9}
        text:"Poll A"

<LoadFilePicker>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: filechooser

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancel()

            Button:

                text: "Load"
                on_release: root.load(filechooser.path, filechooser.selection)
```

Here is the definition of MyLayout class.

```
class MyLayout(FloatLayout):
    def load(self, path, filename):
        self.dismiss_popup()
        db = DataBase(filename)
        db.loadData()

    def dismiss_popup(self):
        self._popup.dismiss()

    def loadPicker(self):
        content = LoadFilePicker(load=self.load, cancel=self.dismiss_popup)
        self._popup = Popup(title="Load file",content=content,size_hint=(0.9, 0.9))
        self._popup.open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `Button` like this:

```
<MyButton@Button>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 200, 100
```

Then use that subclass in `MyLayout`:

```
MyLayout:
    MyButton:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.05, "top":0.95}
        text:"Import config"
        on_release:
            root.loadPicker()

    MyButton:
        pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":0.9}
        text:"Poll A"
```

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways for this, one of the approaches is like below in the MyLayout class:

```
for child in self.children:
    if isinstance(child, Button):
        child.size = 200, 100
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner with Python and Kiwy. Where should i put that ?

Comment: You haven't shared your full code and also didn't mention how you want this size change to be triggered. Hence I have suggested only the snippet. You can put this in a function in MyLayout class.

Comment: I have tried to add it to MyLayout but he didn't worked. I edited my question